# if $\lim a_{n_{j}}=a $ for one subsequence $ (a_{n_{j}}) \subset(a_n)$

Tags: calculus

if $\lim a_{n_{j}}=a $ for one subsequence $ (a_{n_{j}})  \subset(a_n)$. So, $\lim a_{n}=a $. Guys, I stumbled on this statement, but I think that it is false. Could you help me to show that it is false?

Answer (score 6):

By counterexample, set $a_n= (-1)^n$, now for $n_j$ even numbers, $\lim a_{n_j}=1$ but $\lim a_n$ does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Take $a_n=(1,0,1,0,1...)$

So $\lim_{n \to \infty}a_{2n}=0$ but the limit of $a_n$ does not exist.

But there is this useful property  if you want to remember.

> $\lim_{n \to +\infty}a_n =a  \Leftrightarrow \lim_{n \to +\infty} a_{2n}=\lim_{n \to +\infty} a_{2n+1}=a$